# angular subscribe within subscribe button click

Tags: angular, rxjs

I currently have a button which when clicked I want to invoke a service:

```
  saveAssignment(formValues) {
if (this.rulesService.validate(3, 1)) {
    // continue to save
    console.log('trigger save');
    this.assignmentService.saveAssignment(formValues).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('saved!');
  });
} else {
  alert('came in here instead');
    }
  }
```

rules service:

```
validate(actionId: number, referenceId: number): boolean {
let hasErrors = false;
let result: any;
this.validateRulesAPI(3, 1).subscribe((data) => {
  // some logic here will set hasErrors property to true/false
});
    return hasErrors;
  }
```

the ruleService I want it to return a bool whether it validated the params or not, this way i can reuse this, problem though is the order is off as the code returns before the call is complete, is this another way to arrange this, so that they wait for each other?  so rulesService.validate will will wait for the bool to return and then proceed to call saveAssignments if it's returned true? otherwise i see the alert('came in here instead') hitting and then later the validate code runs.

Comment: The way to return an *asynchronous* boolean result is to return an Observable<boolean>. You can't transform an asynchronous call into a synchronous one. Once you have the boolean observable, you can apply operators (filter, for example, to only do something if the boolean is true, and switchMap, to chain another observable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `switchMap` pipeable operator of `rxjs` to subscribe an inner observable.

For validation, you can return an `Observable` that is mapped to `boolean` accordingly:

```
validate(actionId: number, referenceId: number): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.validateRulesAPI(actionId, referenceId).pipe(map(data) => {
         // Do the stuff and check for errors
         // if has error then  ------------>  return false
         // if does not have error then --->  return true
    });
  }
```

Then in `saveAssignment` method you can use `switchMap`

```
saveAssignment(formValues) {
    this.rulesService.validate(3, 1).pipe(
      switchMap((isValid) => {
           if(isValid){
                  return this.assignmentService.saveAssignment(formValues)
           }else{
                  return of(false);  // false or whatever the value you want to have
           }
      })
    ).subscribe((response) => {
        if(response === false){
            alert('Invalid'); // alert('came in here instead');
        }else{
            console.log(response);  // response of this.assignmentService.saveAssignment(formValues)  
        }
    })
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this will work, but I want the saveAssignments to happen outside the validate, as i want to reuse validate in multiple calls.  for example, i want to call validate before saveAssignements, saveXYZ, saveABC.  i wanat validate to tell me if it's ok to proceed to the saves.

Comment: It is already reusable this way. isValid variable is the response of validation. All you have to do is to change the called method in  switchMap to reuse it with any other async operation

Answer (score 0):

You are doing asynchronous validation. It's slightly different from synchronous one.

There is an explanation of how to deal with this kind of validation in [Angular form validation tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#async-validation) which will allow you to let Angular handle the subscriptions.